Get type information of a shared link
We are building a SharePoint files navigation experience with the Microsoft Graph API. We are including a feature in order to be able to copy/paste a link and let the app resolve the container or item.
The API provides provides a shared endpoint which is able to resolve various links:

Links to the site collection root
Links to subsites
Links to document library root
Links to folders
Links to files

Unfortunately we are not able to get specific properties that define the type of the item.
It seems we will need to perform two queries:

/shares/<id>/driveItem
/shares/<id>/site

We then combine the results of both endpoints to deduce the type of item.
If driveItem errors out, we know it is either the root of a site collection or a subsite.
If driveItem yields a result, it contains either a folder property, or a file property.
Although this works, it takes two calls. It would be great if we could just query /shares/<id> with some additional query parameters to get the type and the details of the item.
Any suggestions?
Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get
